# NDSolveValue with Map

Tags: differential-equations

I have:

```
f[x_, y_] = 1 - y;
g[x_, y_] = x^2 - y^2;
sol[{x0_, y_ 0}] := 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
   x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 15}]
```

Then:

```
sol[{2, 1}]
```

Which returns:

```
{InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 15.}}, <>][t], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 15.}}, <>][t]}
```

But when I try:

```
toplot = Map[sol, {{2, 1}}]
```

It returns:

[image]

Notice that there is no comma this time between the first and second interpolating function. Why not?

Comment: There is a comma if I do as you input. However, it seems that you asked for `MatrixForm`, and the matrix form of a list does not have comma in between elements.

Comment: That is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After correcting the typo in the argument to `sol` (`{x0_, y_ 0}` to `{x0_, y0_}`), I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
f[x_, y_] = 1 - y;
g[x_, y_] = x^2 - y^2;
sol[{x0_, y0_}] := 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], x[0] == x0, 
   y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 15}]

toplot = Map[sol, {{2, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
 Plot[toplot, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I've discovered it myself this morning.